# Looking for a verb formed from a plural noun

Tags: verbs

Almost any singular noun can be verbed, transformed into a verb means to remove (*skin*), apply (*paint*), use (*bus*), or otherwise interact with the noun.

I'm looking for a plural noun that can be verbed.  I have only two, frankly terrible, examples:

- *[times](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133093/the-word-times-instead-of-multiplied-by/133099)*, which has a very childish sound to my ears
- *[mules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulesing)*, which refers to a surgical procedure performed on sheep, and is named for a Dr. Mules, and not the sturdy equine, although I assume the name of the eponymous vet originally derives from that animal.

Is there a true example?  Tell me that *to cats* someone is a thing.

Comment: were you ever pantsed in grade school?

Comment: to twin something maybe

Comment: There is currently a [question in ELL in which some commenters/answerers posit *times* as a conjugated verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133093/the-word-times-instead-of-multiplied-by) (e.g. *I **timesed** 3 and 4*). It sounds flat wrong that way to me, but apparently it works in some corners of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @1006a -- "some" answerer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are a few words that are like this, even more if both slang and obscure/obsolete words are included (that's actually most of the list). I found these with an advanced search on OED:

- balls/bollocks (slang)
- (de-)pants (slang)
- discommons (historical & rare)
- guts (colloquial)
- quicksticks (slang, rare, & possibly formed from adj not noun)
- sessions (slang)
- suds
- times (there is another, non-colloquial meaning in Building & Surveying)
- twos (colloquial)

If you include irregular plurals, there is:

- dice
- people

Comment: Hahaha -- I actually had `pants` on my list of verbed nouns and didn't notice it was a plural!  Is `ballsing` a word?  What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a number off the top of my head:

- cups
- groups
- heads
- faces
- numbers
- plates
- forks
- spoons

Comment: Hello, Nancy. ELU requires answers that are backed up by authoritative references (note that Laurel found those examples in the OED).

Answer (score -1):

**Numerals:**
(the golfer) bogey-*fived* the eighth
(batsman) *centuried* with an off-drive.

**collectives:**
to *regiment* a collection of pencils;
to *convoy* a group of students;
to *team* up with a casual acquaintance;

Comment: i'd add to sixtynine with someone?

Comment: A numeral is a numeral; I would not call it a plural noun.

Comment: @P.O. -- I'm sure you would, but this isn't plentyoffish.com